# Create a JQuery dialog modal function with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am a bit newbie in Jquery and java scripts and a bit confuse in this matter.
Here's my code of a simple modal message alert taken from JQuery UI.

The problem is that the function is being called in the div class in the HTML code:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
  </p>
  <p>
    Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
  </p>
</div>
```

But what i want to do is to create 2 parameters: 1 receives some text and the 2nd is when i press ok it goes to a link.

I am developing a website and i don't want to use the browsers alert, just want to use that JQuery script and do something like this:

```
<?php
    function alerta($texto="",$redirect=""){
        print("<Script language=javascript>");
        if($texto!="")
            print("alert(\"$texto\");");
        if($redirect!="")
            print("window.location=\"$redirect\";");
        print("</script>");
    }
?>
```

Comment: You want to echo a variable that contains an string from PHP, and then the second variable will be URL to be redirected when clicking "OK" button in modal window?

Comment: Exactly and then call the function everywhere i want.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo your text (Variable 1) inside the div modal, and then use the redirect function on 'OK' button click event:

```
$(function() {
     $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
       modal: true,
       buttons: {
         Ok: function() {
              window.location = "$YOUR_VARIABLE_2";
         }
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: The thing is i am going to use this dialog message a lot and i don't want write this function in every single html page that requires a dialog message.

Comment: Well, that's simple, as you're using PHP, use `include('php_file_with_modal_code.php');`

Comment: Yes i know but i don't have the 2 declared parameters i want like in my php alert function right?

Comment: You can't declare those parameters togheter in the `php_file_with_modal_code.php` file?

Comment: Well, that' the issue i'm confused.

Comment: Well, to help you would be best if you could provide your current code, how are you setting up those variable and how you're trying to get them.

Comment: In my php function its like this:
alerta("Your registration is complete","index.html");

I just want to do that with my js function